# Second drive not allowing user accounts access

Tags: mount, permissions, hard-drive

This problem recently started when I added about 5 new user accounts to the workstation, Before that this problem did not exist.

I am running Ubuntu on a SSD and have two other drives that contain files data etc. I have multiple users on the workstation. When I look at the properties of the drive it has the owner as the user that mounted the drive and will not allow any other user to access the drive unless they unmount and remount the drive, which then takes away access to the previous user. When I look at the permissions of the drive they are only for the owner and It will not allow me to change them with sudo chmod. It doesn't matter who the owner is I just need everyone to be able to access the drive without remounting it.

I have looked all over forums and have not been able to find this problem anywhere or anything common to it.

Comment: What file system do the other partitions use?

Comment: All the partitions use ext3/ext4. Don't know if this matters but there is 1 partition per drive totaling 3 drives.

Answer (score 0):

```
df -h
```

Copy the location where the drive is mounted. Then enter

```
sudo chmod -R 777 /mounted/on/location
```

Comment: I'd rather recommend `755` completely enough.

Comment: I assume he needs everyone to be able to write on the other drives. @AKirner: If you don't need everyone to be able to write, use 755.

Comment: I need everyone to have complete access so I need the drive set at 777 and then the users can change their personal file permissions after that if they wish.

Comment: I am also I am pretty green when it comes to linux and dont understand what you mean when you say /mounted/on/location

Comment: @AKirner Make sure to use the switch -R (capital R) so the change is applied to all files and folders. With /mounted/on/location I mean the location where the partition is mounted. If you mount the drives using Nautilus (the standard file browser of Ubuntu) this will be a folder in /media/yourUsername/ . Just go to the root of the partition in Nautilus (like when you click on it in the navigation on the left) and press ctrl+L. This will show you your current location and you can copy it to the clipboard.

Comment: If I followed the instructions right then the Solution didn't work. After I did the chmod I switched to a test user and tried to access the drive and It said access was still not allowed.

Comment: Please mount the partition and post the output of `df -h` and the exact command you used here.

Comment: manilaworkshop2014@manilaworkshop2014-VirtualBox:~$ df -h
df: ‘/run/user/1001/gvfs’: Permission denied
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda1        35G  8.8G   25G  27% /
/dev/sdc1       466G  152G  315G  33% /media/manilaworkshop2014/Holy Grail
/dev/sdb        7.8G  2.1G  5.3G  29% /media/manilaworkshop2014/Koele
manilaworkshop2014@manilaworkshop2014-VirtualBox:~$ sudo chmod -R 777 /media/manilaworkshop2014/Koele

Comment: I couldnt get the comment to keep the formatting I gave it

Comment: If there is a blank or certain characters the location must be in quotes. But since the one you tried it first with doesn't contain such characters it works without them. I have no idea why it doesn't work. The only think left to try is to run `sudo chown -R yourUsername /mounted/on/location` and then the chmod command. If this doesn't work I don't know what to do and you must hove for someone else to help you.

Comment: Of course there still is the option of using a FS (file system) with a less sophisticated access right system. Microsoft's FS do a pretty good job at not having such stuff. So you can format your partitions to NTFS (make sure to have a copy of your files since this will delete all files currently on the partition) and won't have this trouble. However, Microsoft's FS come with an awful lot of downsides to a Linux user but if you previously used Windows you had the cope with these downsides before and in this regard nothing will change. (Of course your actual system FS fill be unaffected.)

Comment: I just changed the owner to the other account and It still doesn't have access to the drive. And as with the NTFS I have that on a different drive and it has the same problem.

Comment: When I ls -l the drive it says this                       drwxrwxrwx 4 test manilaworkshop2014  4096 Mar 30 17:03 Koele
so I don’t know what’s going on. Are the users not in the group or something?

Comment: It seems that the problem isn't the access to the FS but rather to the mounting point. `sudo chmod -R 777 /media/manilaworkshop2014`, maybe even `sudo chmod -R 777 /media`

Comment: I think the sudo media fixed it. I wa testing everything on a VM so I have to go in and change the actual workstations. Will update and close the question if It fixes it. I appreciate your time and effort.